# Setting up CentOS/RHEL virtual on VirtualBox

Tags: centos, redhat, configuration, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I have a physical server running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga). I would like to create a virtual machine (using VirtualBox) with a binary-compatible version of CentOS server as this RHEL server version, and have a few questions:

1. Which version of CentOS server should I use to match RHEL 5.5?
2. Are their special VBox configurations (special drivers, settings, etc.) that I should be aware of (specific to RHEL/CentOS) before creating this virtual?

And if this is not possible to do with CentOS, are there any other possible (free) solutions you can think of? For instance, is it possible to download a trial/evaluation version of RHEL server 5.5, make an image of it, and use that as the virtual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS version number basically matches the RHEL version numbering, so you will want to get a copy of [CentOS 5.5 from their vault](http://vault.centos.org/5.5/isos/), as the current release in the 5.x line is 5.9.

I don't recall any special settings that are needed for a CentOS guest on VirtualBox, if only to get the thing running.  A plain vanilla install should work.  You will, of course, want to match up settings in the VM to your production machine, eventually.